# When trying to retrieve data from the database I get an error "InvalidOperationException was unhandled"

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a form named `Form1`:

There is one `ComboBox` and one `TextBox`, when I select US$ from the `ComboBox` then it must retrieve data from the database and display 150 in the `TextBox`.

This is myform code:

For `ComboBox`;

```
namespace PCJ_System
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

     private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "server = DESKTOP-LKEG8FM\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog= PCJ_DB ; Integrated Security=True;";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str);
        conn.Open();
        conn = new SqlConnection(str);
        string GetData = "Select [FC_Rate] from Forcur where FC_TYPE ='" + comboBox1.Text + "' ";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(GetData, conn);
        var returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        textBox1.Text = returnValue.ToString();
        conn.Close();
    }

  }
}
```

My database table Forcur:

```
ID |FC_TYPE |FC_RATE|
1   US$      150
2   UK#      210
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Don't munge query strings with user input values.  Learn to use parameters!

Comment: And what is the *message* in the exception? Also, the *first* thing you should do is stop building SQL with values like that - use parameterized SQL instead. Currently your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, as well as conversion and general readability issues.

Comment: error Message i get is InvalidOperationException was unhandled”:
 {"ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized."}

Comment: So then that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the exact answer you are looking for, but you need to take care of following:

1) Assign DB connection string to `SqlConnection` object and open connection.

2) Since you are assigning one value to textbox, you need to use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteReader`

Once you fix this, you should get the desired result.

Example:

```
conn=new SqlConnection(connectionStringHere);
conn.Open();
string GetData = "Select [FC_Rate] from Forcur where FC_TYPE ='" + comboBox1.Text + "' ";
cmd = new SqlCommand(GetData, conn);
var returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

textBox1.Text = returnValue.ToString();
conn.close();
```

> Note: You still have SQL injection attack open in your SQL query. Try using varables instead to stop that.

Comment: its showing an error:{"ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed."}

Comment: @Nimo I mentioned in answer to open connection. But forgot to add in code example. Added it now. Should work